# iOS safely pass content between apps

Tags: ios, security, mobile, oauth, keychain

I'm curious if there is a way to safely pass content between apps on iOS. The ultimate goal is to implement oauth between two ios apps.

Since apps are not guaranteed to have unique url schemes, this option is out.

I have considered using keychain groups, but do not have experience with this. It looks like an app needs to specify exactly which apps can access the keychain items.

Are there any other options? Is there some sort of identifier (such as android bundle ID) that can be used to verify the apps during a request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL schemes for this.

### The basic process

You'll have a ServerApp and many ClientApps. The ServerApp listens to an URL-scheme like `serverapp://`. The client then can make a call to the server to ask it for authentication. The client has to implement an URL-scheme too. E.g. ClientAppOne implements the URL scheme `clientapp1://`. The server takes as parameter a backlink to the client app. E.g. the client calls the URL `serverapp://auth?back=clientapp1%3A%2F%2Fserverapp-auth` (here the backlink is `clientapp1://serverapp-auth` and has been urlencoded).

The server then checks the users identity, asks him for permission, password, etc. and then uses the backlink to provide the data. How the backlink works exactly is application specific, but you usually need at least 2 parts: an access token and a username. E.g. a backlink will then be `clientapp1://serverapp-auth?success=1&token=fi83ia8wfzi3s8fi8s3f8si8sf&user=robert` or maybe in case of error `clientapp1://serverapp-auth?success=0&errno=421`. The client then needs to verify the accesstoken through some public (or private) API, e.g. `https://serverapp.example.com/userdetails?apikey=fai83jw93fj93389j&token=fi83ia8wfzi3s8fi8s3f8si8sf`. The server will return some structured response.

### Necessary components

1. an URL scheme on the server App
2. an URL scheme on each client App
3. an SDK that is to be included into each client app and that handels the details of authentication, and a standard UI component (e.g. facebook has a standard button that says "login with facebook", so the ServerApp needs some re-recognizable button that says something like "login with ServerApp")
4. a server that provides services that can be accessed through the access token.
5. a defined API that explains how the client has to communicate with the server
6. an SDK to be included into the client that handels such client-server-communication (should be part of the SDK mentioned in component 3.)
7. maybe a wiki that documents all of the steps above, so that you and other developers dont lose track
8. a way to invalidate access tokens, and a way for the client to detect if an access token has been invalidated. furthermore, if the user changes his password, all access tokens should be invalidated.

### Random notes

1. in your client app you can check if the serverapp is installed by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"serverapp://auth"]]`.
2. the URL schemes should be sufficently collission-free. These URLs are never seen by users, only by developers, so they don't have to be beautiful. You can e.g. append the iTunes-Connect-App-ID to your URL-scheme, like `serverapp1234567://`. This will greatly reduce the possibility that someday some other app will use the same URL scheme.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response. I'm not sure if I'm following, though. Maybe I didn't explain my question well enough. Because there is a chance that schemes can collide, I cannot be certain that when an app passes content to another through schemes that it will be talking to the right app. Therefore, schemes are inherently vulnerable and cannot be used for oauth.

Comment: if you name your scheme well, it can only collide if some other app-author intentionally implements the same scheme. passwords will never be passed between apps. a malicious client may implement the same scheme as a particular valid client and maybe intercept the back-link and send the token to some compromised server. if such a thing happens you should report it to apple. a malicious server may get a login request from some client. in all these scenarios security is already compromised, because you have a malicious app installed. you can of course also encrypt the data you pass around...

Comment: @RobertKotcher also, I fear that you will not find a more secure way to achieve your goals...

Comment: this is what I'm concerned about also. And using ssl does not protect against this attack because attacker does not need to intercept data. Malicious user just has to write same exact scheme into his app, and once user installs it, all data will be passed to malicious app.

Comment: I've found some iOS apps that I have not been able to compromise in this way though, and I'm very interested how they're able to overcome this. I've tried installing my malicious app (research) before and after legit app, regardless this attempt does not work for some apps.

Comment: @RobertKotcher I'm curious if you ever found out how those apps prevented scheme interception?